# Calculating max ,mean and min of a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Calculated the mean, max and mean of a column in dataframe as follows:

```
    g['MAX range'] = g['Current_range'].max()
    g['min range'] = g['Current_range'].min()
    g['mean'] = g['Current_range'].mean()
```

The output was as follows:

```
current_speed current_range maxrange minrange mean
10             25             190       25      74
20             40             190       25      74
20             41             190       25      74
80             190            190       25      74
```

i dont want to get repeated values in max range,min range,mean but only single values in those columns.

Expected output:

```
current_speed current_range maxrange minrange mean
10             25             190       25      74
20             40             
20             41             
80             190
```

How can i modify it?

Comment: Could you edit your example data to be complete and self-contained? I can't reproduce any of the expected numbers like `185`, `27`, or `128` with what you've shared so far. Also, what does `values` in the last row represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add it with `.loc`. Example for `mean`:

```
g.loc[g.index[0], 'mean'] = g['Current_range'].mean()
```

It will create column mean with mean value in the first row and `NaN` values for other rows.